# Viewing output when the "The plugin generated x characters of unexpected output during activation" error is triggered

Tags: activation

I'm working on a plugin and having some difficulties getting a new table created. I get the "The plugin generated x characters of unexpected output during activation" error. Is there a way of viewing the actual error? I believe that a redirect is involved in this process, hence the reason I don't see the actual error output. I have all error reporting and logging on, but still I get nothing.

Comment: I figured out a way to see the error--I executed `exit()` on line 1569 of wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php. It is called at the end of the dbDelta function, which allowed me to see the output that was generated and quickly fix the problem. I'm still interested in learning other methods for this that would not require a core hack.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly the ability to display errors and output from a plugin on activation seems to be build in to WordPress. If you take a look at `wp-admin/plugins.php` there's a case in the `$action` switch statement that says `error_scrape` -- hinted at in Lars' answer.

Looks like this:

```
<?php
// wp-admin/plugins.php
case 'error_scrape':
    if ( ! current_user_can('activate_plugins') )
        wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to activate plugins for this site.'));

    check_admin_referer('plugin-activation-error_' . $plugin);

    $valid = validate_plugin($plugin);
    if ( is_wp_error($valid) )
        wp_die($valid);

    if ( ! WP_DEBUG ) {
        error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
    }

    @ini_set('display_errors', true); //Ensure that Fatal errors are displayed.
    // Go back to "sandbox" scope so we get the same errors as before
    function plugin_sandbox_scrape( $plugin ) {
        include( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $plugin );
    }
    plugin_sandbox_scrape( $plugin );
    do_action('activate_' . $plugin);
    exit;
    break;
```

As you can see, it mimics the plugin activation senario, but it doesn't actually activate the plugin. It includes the plugin file, calls the activate hook, then exits. It does all this without output buffering so you can see what's happening.

SO, if that's already there, we just need to expose it. A bit of digging in `wp-admin/plugins.php` shows we need a nonce to verify. So we can copy that and study how the plugins list table builds its activation links. Then simply add an error scrape link on the inactive plugins. Click it, and see your errors.

Just hook into `plugin_action_links` and add the link:

```
<?php
add_filter('plugin_action_links', 'wpse24278_add_scrape', 10, 2);
/**
 * Add an "Error Scrape" action to inactive plugins.
 *
 * @uses    is_plugin_active
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse24278_add_scrape($actions, $plugin)
{
    global $status, $page, $s;

    // leave active plugins alone
    if (is_plugin_active($plugin)) {
        return $actions;
    }

    // build the url, identical to the activate URL, see the
    // plugings list table for more information.
    $url = add_query_arg(array(
        'action'            => 'error_scrape',
        'plugin'            => $plugin,
        'plugin_status'     => $status,
        'paged'             => $page,
        's'                 => $s,
    ), admin_url('plugins.php'));

    // add our action.
    $actions['error_scrape'] = sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" title="%s" class="edit">%s</a>',
        wp_nonce_url($url, 'plugin-activation-error_' . $plugin), // see `wp-admin/plugins.php` for the nonce name
        esc_attr__('Check for Errors', 'wpse'),
        esc_html__('Error Scrape', 'wpse')
    );

    return $actions;
}
```

Here is the above [wrapped up in a plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/error-scrape.php).

Comment: I wish there was a way to +1 this a hundred times. You just made my day.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, so I had a look on Google and some guy named Jason had a solution:

```
br_trigger_error('Some error message', E_USER_ERROR);

function br_trigger_error($message, $errno) {
  if(isset($_GET['action'])
      &amp;&amp; $_GET['action'] == 'error_scrape') {
    echo '<strong>' . $message . '</strong>';
    exit;
} else {
    trigger_error($message, $errno);
}
}
```

From http://www.squarepenguin.com/wordpress/?p=6 that has more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way, all props to [**itzco**](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/the-plugin-generated-xxxx-characters-of-unexpected-output) and [**hungrycoder**](http://thehungrycoder.com/wordpress/how-i-have-solved-the-the-plugin-generated-xxxx-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-problem.html). I've added the hook parameters.

```
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'save_error_wpse_24278', 10, 2 );

function save_error_wpse_24278( $plugin, $network_wide )
{
    file_put_contents( 
        WP_CONTENT_DIR. '/error_activation.html', 
        $plugin . ob_get_contents() 
    );
    //update_option( 'plugin_error',  ob_get_contents() );
}
```

Comment: Would be better with [`wp_upload_dir`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) instead of a hardcoded path to wp-content.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy, I guess `WP_CONTENT_DIR` does the same job, and I think it makes more sense in there than inside `/uploads/`...

Comment: My WP_CONTENT_DIR is not writable, just my uploads folder. If that's anything.